# how to change values of a column in sas dataset

Tags: sas

my dataset is like this
[image]

I want to change all 'Within the next 6 months' to '< 6 Months'
Similarly all of the 'Between 6 months and a year' to '6 to 12 months'

How can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the below and just load in any others values of `wait_time` you need to change:

```
data input ;
  set input ;
  select (wait_time) ;
    when ('Within the next 6 months')    wait_time='<6 Months' ;
    when ('Between 6 months and a year') wait_time='6 to 12 Months' ;
    otherwise ;
  end ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use the tranwrd function as in the following example (please not it has not been written in the most efficient way):

```
data out1;
    set src;
    text = tranwrd(text, "Within the next 6 months", "< 6 Months");
    text = tranwrd(text, "Between 6 months and a year", "6 to 12 months");
run;
```

An alternative solution may involve using formats:

```
proc format;
    value $sample_format
        "Within the next 6 months"="< 6 Months"
        "Between 6 months and a year"="6 to 12 months"
        ;
run;
data out2;
    set src;
    text = put(text, $sample_format.);
run;
```